# How to select all vertices of a model with a boundary box in THREE?

Tags: three.js, kdtree

I have a model comprised of millions of vertices. I'd like to select all vertices that fall within a boundary box defined as a set of (X, Y) coordinates with any Z value.

I understand the most efficient way to search through a set of vertices would be to leverage a Kd Tree, however, with the nearest neighbor algorithms, I can only get points near one particular vertex. How would I be able to extend this functionality to select all vertices in a 2D range with any Z value?

Comment: Do you want to get a sub-set (array of points or their indices) or, for example, just change the colour of those points?

Comment: I would like to get the actual vertices of these points and later perform some treatment to them or add other objects to the scene at those coordinates.

Comment: I would try coding this up, "brute force", first. If you can render these vertices in WebGL, filtering them one-by-one with a bounding box is not out of the question. If necessary, look at tools like [rbush](https://github.com/mourner/rbush). If you don't care about the Z value, 2D algorithms are fine.